# Inserting Current date and current time in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table in Oracle DBMS with the following columns.

```
 |------|--------------------------|---------------------------|-------------------|
 | Name | "Log in Time" (HH:MM:SS) | "Log out time" (HH:MM:SS) | Day (DD-MMM-YYYY) |
 | -----|--------------------------|---------------------------|-------------------|
```

In the "Log in Time" column i have to insert the current time in the above mentioned format.
In the Day column i have to insert the current date in the above mentioned format.

I know how to get it done in one line IBM DB2. 
But how do i achieve it in Oracle SQL Insert query?

Comment: Are your columns declared as `VARCHAR2`?  Or are they declared as a proper data type (`DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`)?  Are you really using case-sensitive identifiers for your column names?

Comment: The "Day" column is a proper DATE datatype. The "Log in Time" and "Log out time" columns are of VARCHAR2 datatypes.

Comment: A `DATE` column does not have a format.  And it always includes a day and a time.  Do you want the `Day` column to include the same time that is stored in the `"Log in Time"` column (which makes the "Log in Time" column rather redundant)?

Comment: The DATE column in my case does not hold the time. So I don't think ther will redundancy here. Anyway I achieved it by having the host code itself pass the modified time in VARCHAR format. I did a lot of searching and didn't find a way to achieve it in Oracle. Thankyou so much for your help...!

Comment: A `DATE` column must contain a time.  Every single Oracle `DATE` contains a time.  Now, it's possible that you are always storing a time of midnight in which case you're not storing redundant data.  You're storing misleading data.